# Django ImageField not uploading files to media folder nothing helps

Tags: python, django

I was seen all themes and tutorials and docs that i found, but i don't solved my problem.

ImageField upload_to don't upload files to media folder.

settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

models.py

```
image = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to = "images/")
```

File loading from form is correct. In template on {{ object.image.url }} i see path media/name.png

Database field showing name of file: name.png

But file name.png NOT EXISTS in folder media. Folder media was created.

Comment: you uploaded to ```"images/"```, why the path is media/name.png? it should be images/name.png. Do you see if images folder created in media folder?

Comment: Yes. I don't know why this. No Images folder not creating

Comment: just to make sure, do you have ```enctype="multipart/form-data"``` in your form?

Comment: Oh, I find problem. Function "update" for model object don't call "upload_to" method.  It's not obvious. I need to delete object and create again with new image. Why so?

Comment: maybe you should show some code for your views and urls?